# Password confirmation with Passport

Tags: node.js, passwords, ejs, passport.js

I've created a basic user registration form which works fine but I need to add a confirm password field.

My form is as follows:

```
<div class ="container form">

<div class="jumbotron form"><h2><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Signup</h2></div>
<form action = "/register" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter username" name="username"> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type = "password" class ="form-control" placeholder = "Enter password" name="password1">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <label for="password">Confirm password</label>
        <input type = "password" class ="form-control" placeholder = "Enter password" name = "password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <label for="img">Image</label>
        <input type = "text" class ="form-control" placeholder = "Enter image URL" name = "image">
</div>
    <button type ="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Signup</button>
</form>
</div>
```

So when a user hits submit, I obviously need the 2 password inputs to match and an error to be thrown if they don't.

I'm using Passport for authenitcation. I have the following setup:

```
// passport configuration
app.use(require("express-session")({
secret: "maidenJones",
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
app.use(expressSanitizer());

app.use(function(req, res, next){
res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
next();
});
```

Register route:

```
router.post("/register", function(req, res){
var newUser = new User({username: req.body.username, image: req.body.image});
User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
if(err){
    res.redirect("/blogs");
    console.log(err);
} 
passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
    res.redirect("/blogs");
});
});
});
```

Not sure where to start to implement the password confirmation check

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your registration logic inside the passport LocalStrategy and then use that strategy as a middleware in your routes.

**Example:**

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'passwd'
},
function(req, username, password, done) {
    // User register logic
  }
));

router.post('/register', 
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/register' }),
    function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/blogs');
});
```

more info here: [passport-localstrategy](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not sure I entirely understand. Where does this check that the 2 password fields match? Not sure how to implement this into my code

Comment: you should validate your form on the client side before submitting using jquery or angular. if that's not the case and you want to validate it on the server side (can't see why tho), you still have to do it inside the localstrategy.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit of a novice at this. So essentially the password confirm field wouldn't be submitted? It's just a field to compare?

Comment: The whole form shouldn't be submitted since the 2 passwords don't match. it should throw an error. Password confirmation is made to prevent the user from registering with a wrong password giving him "a second chance" to write the right one, simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

```
passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
usernameField: 'email',
passwordField: 'password',
passReqToCallback: true
```

},

```
function (req, email, password, done) {
    //All validation logic comes here
    let password1 = req.body.password;
    let password2 = req.body.password2;
    req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid email').notEmpty().isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password must be more than 4 characters')
        .not().isEmpty().isLength({ min: 4 });
    let errors = req.validationErrors();
    //just to see the output in your console
    console.log(password1);
    console.log(password2);
    if (errors) {
        let messages = [];
        errors.forEach(function (error) {
            messages.push(error.msg);
        });
        return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));

    } else if (password1 !== password2) {
        return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'Password and Confirm Password must match'));
    }
     // You can then continue your code logic(submitting to database)
```

Comment: The password1 and password2 are name values from your form fields.